# How do I connect Visual Studio Code to SQL Server LocalDB for code first migration?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, ef-code-first

I am trying to migrate my database using Visual Studio Code and SQL Server. I have specified the connection string by replacing the `DefaultConnection` value from `app.db` with my own connection string in `appsettings.json`, but it looks like it doesn't recognize the usual connection string format.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TDbContext>. This class will be used only at design time.

*[IDesignTimeDbContextFactory IDesignTimeDbContextFactory IDesignTimeDbContextFactory IDesignTimeDbContextFactory Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.1)*

```
    class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DbContext>
    {
        public DbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();

            builder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost; Database=DatabaseName; User ID=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword;");
            return new DbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
```